# My internet comes from my iPhone tethered to my desktop, can I connect a router to this?

Tags: networking, router, internet, iphone

I have internet on my desktop from my cel phone which is tethered.  I have devices which were formerly connected to my home network through the DSL modem, but I can't use them now because at some point they need a hardwired connection.  Is there some way I can connect a router (I have a couple Linksys routers) to my internet connection so I can hardwire these devices to the router?  I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: The iPhone _is_ your router. A router is what routes packets between networks, and that is the function served by your iPhone.

Comment: I think you're asking if you can share you internet connection, provided by the iPhone with other devices.  If that's correct then that's the question you should ask and there are ways to do it.

Comment: But it would probably also violate your terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

What are the version numbers of your routers? If they are wrtg54 v2 - 8 then yes you can use them. You would need to load new software onto them. dd-wrt / openwrt or tomato I believe would do the job. Reply back with the model numbers and versions of your Linksys routers and I will try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Cradlepoint routers have this capability, as does Cisco Meraki.

> Establishing a Hotspot Connection: If your device has the capability
>   to create a Wi-Fi Hotspot, it can be used in conjunction with Series 3
>   Cradlepoint routers' WiFi as WAN feature. Please use this link if you
>   are using firmware version 6.

http://knowledgebase.cradlepoint.com/articles/Support/Unsupported-Modem-or-Phone?retURL=%2Fapex%2FknowledgeSearch%3Fc%3DAll_Products%26k%3Dtether%26lang%3Den_US&popup=false&c=All_Products&lang=en_US